# Cannot save java date to Cassandra

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

I try to save some data using spark to casandra, but when i try to save Date i got

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   Can't extract value from field2#5;    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExtractValue$.apply(complexTypeExtractors.scala:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:475)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:467)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:339)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:339)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:338)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)  at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)   at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:332)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TreeNode.scala:298)
>     at
>   scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues$$anonfun$iterator$3.apply(MapLike.scala:246)
>     at
>   scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues$$anonfun$iterator$3.apply(MapLike.scala:246)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)  at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)   at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)    at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$$anon$1.foreach(IterableLike.scala:294)
>     at
>   scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:24)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableViewLike$class.force(TraversableViewLike.scala:87)
>     at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$$anon$1.force(IterableLike.scala:294)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)  at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)   at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:332)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)  at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)   at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:332)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TreeNode.scala:298)
>     at
>   scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues$$anonfun$iterator$3.apply(MapLike.scala:246)
>     at
>   scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues$$anonfun$iterator$3.apply(MapLike.scala:246)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)  at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)   at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)    at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$$anon$1.foreach(IterableLike.scala:294)
>     at
>   scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:24)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableViewLike$class.force(TraversableViewLike.scala:87)
>     at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$$anon$1.force(IterableLike.scala:294)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)  at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)   at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:332)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)  at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)   at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:332)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionUp$1(QueryPlan.scala:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2(QueryPlan.scala:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:122)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2(QueryPlan.scala:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlan.scala:127)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)  at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)   at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:467)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:347)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.apply(Analyzer.scala:347)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.apply(Analyzer.scala:328)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
>     at
>   scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.resolve(ExpressionEncoder.scala:294)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.(Dataset.scala:79)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.(Dataset.scala:90)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.as(DataFrame.scala:209)    at
>   casandra.casandra.App.readFromSqlServer(App.java:55)  at
>   casandra.casandra.App.main(App.java:76)

Error apperas on:

```
 Dataset<Table1> tData = dataFrame.as(Encoders.bean(Table1.class));
 List<Table1> tList = tData.collectAsList();
```

My table class

```
public class Table1 {
    private String field1;
    private Date field2;
}
```

My cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE "a"."table1" (
field1 text,
field2 timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY (( field1 )));
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Edit:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
conf.setAppName("Casandra Test");
conf.setMaster("local[*]");
conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", adress);
App app = new App(conf);
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
 Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
options.put("url", sqlServerAddress);
options.put("dbtable", "(SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1");
options.put("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
DataFrame dataFrame = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(options).load();        
Dataset<table1> ceData = dataFrame.as(Encoders.bean(Table1.class));
List<table1> ceList = ceData.collectAsList();           
JavaRDD<table1> ceRDD = sc.parallelize(app.readFromSqlServer(sqlContext));
javaFunctions(ceRDD).writerBuilder("a", "table1", mapToRow(Table1.class)).saveToCassandra();
sc.stop();
```

Comment: Can you please give the complete spark code ? Especially when you call the `saveToCassandra()` method

Comment: @doanduyhai: i added this part of code, but my app crash before it.

Comment: Please show the complete code from "dataFrame.as(Encoders.bean(Table1.class));" until the "saveToCassandra". Right now it's not understandable at all ...

Comment: @doanduyhai I submit complete code.

Comment: Something weird I can see, shouldn't it be **Table1.class** instead of **table1.class** (capital **T** letter) ?

Comment: And can you paste the complete exception stack ?

Comment: Ok the Encoders cannot encode the JavaBean **Table1**. Did you create **public constructor** and **getters/setters** for this class ?

Comment: @doanduyhai  Ok, now i have other error

Comment: @doanduyhai its alredy posted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I've found your issue.

If you look at the official documentation for method [`Encoders.bean()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$), it says:

```
Creates an encoder for Java Bean of type T.

T must be publicly accessible.

supported types for java bean field:

- primitive types: boolean, int, double, etc.
- boxed types: Boolean, Integer, Double, etc.
- String
- java.math.BigDecimal
- time related: java.sql.Date, java.sql.Timestamp
- collection types: only array and java.util.List currently, map support is in progress
nested java bean.
```

**`java.util.Date`** type is not mentioned so it's **not supported** by **`Encoders`**

You should update your `Table1` class to use another type rather than `java.util.Date`

Comment: Ok, now i changed type to sql.date and it's gots me org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 82, Column 85: No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters "long"; candidates are: "public static java.sql.Date org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils.toJavaDate(int)"

Comment: It's normal, your type is `java.sql.Date` and Cassandra column type is `timestamp` and it does not match. I recommend to use `Long` type in your `Table1` and `bigint` type in Cassandra and perform the conversion yourself in the application. It's unfortunate that Spark **Encoders** cannot support `java.util.Date`

Comment: Thank u, it works. But It is a pity that date is not supported